# Conditionally adding an object to another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, pdf

### Background

I've been writing a library in Google App Script for my company that sends out an email based on parameters a user assigns. This function is similar to Google's `MailApp.sendEmail()` function. Building off of that function, I've been working on a way that allows a user to take a sheet from a spreadsheet and send that as a PDF in the email as well. This is determined through an object `{sheet: 'sheet to be PDF', name: 'PDF name', type: 'portrait'}`, with the `sheet` key determining which sheet will be converted and sent as a PDF, `name` key determining the name of the PDF, and `type` key being whether the PDF is sent out in either portrait or landscape mode. An example of what this function call would look like is: `sendEmail('person@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body', 'otherperson@gmail.com', {sheet: 'sheet1', name: 'PDF_name', type: 'landscape'}`. So in this case, an email will be sent to the email address `person@gmail.com` with `otherperson@gmail.com` being cc'd to the email. The email that is sent, the subject line will read as `subject`, with the body of the email only saying `body`. The object at the end does something further. If your code is attached to a spreadsheet, it will locate the sheet with the name `sheet1`, convert that into a PDF, setting the name of the newly created PDF as `PDF_name` and setting that PDF in `landscape` mode.

I have it set up so that if someone wants to send a sheet as a PDF, but they do not specify what they want the name of the PDF to be set to or type of orientation they want the PDF to be in, then the name of the PDF will just be the sheet `name` and the `type` will just be portrait mode. The issue that arises is in a switch-case statement, specifically this one:

### Assumed Problem Code

```
if(arguments.length >= 4){
      switch(true){
        case validateEmail(arguments[3]):
          options.cc = arguments[3]

        case (isObject(arguments[3]) && arguments.length === 4)|| isObject(arguments[4]):
          options.pdf = {
            sheet: arguments[3].sheet,
            name: arguments[3].name,
            type: arguments[3].type
          }
          tempName(options)
      }
    }
```

My understanding of how switch-case statements work is when the switch argument is set to `true`, it will only execute the specific case if the argument/value/whatever returns true. An example case where it keeps failing is when the function is called, the arguments are `sendEmail('person@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body', 'otherperson@gmail.com')`.

In my example, since there are 4 arguments, it should run through the switch-case, and should return true for the first case, as it is an email. It would then proceed to the next case because there is no break after the first case. However, it should return false because the email will not be an object, but a string. The issue is that even though it does not pass that case, it still creates the object and adds it to the options object that was created earlier in the script. I'm not sure why this is happening, as not passing that case shouldn't create that object, and shouldn't then proceed to the `tempName()` function call. Any assistance or advice is appreciated. I will also link all of the remaining relevant code below:

This is not relevant to the issue, but I should explain it as well. The `tempName()` function call is just for checking when a user IS adding the object, it checks if those values are null. It then sets them to default parameters so the PDF will have the same name as the sheet being converted into a PDF and type of PDF will be portrait mode. It then proceeds to another function call that converts it into a PDF properly.

### Relevant Code

```
function sendEmail(){
  try{
    const options = {
      to: arguments[0],
      subject: arguments[1],
      body: arguments[2],
    }

    if(arguments.length >= 4){
      switch(true){
        case validateEmail(arguments[3]):
          options.cc = arguments[3]

        case (isObject(arguments[3]) && arguments.length === 4)|| isObject(arguments[4]):
          options.pdf = {
            sheet: arguments[3].sheet,
            name: arguments[3].name,
            type: arguments[3].type
          }
          tempName(options)
      }
    }
    
    function tempName(options){
      Logger.log(options)
      switch(true){
        case options.pdf.name == null:
          options.pdf.name = options.pdf.sheet

        case options.pdf.type == null:
          options.pdf.type = 'portrait'
      }
      return options.attachments = [pdf(options.pdf.sheet, options.pdf.type).setName(options.pdf.name)]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(options)
  
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}
```

### Other Potentially Relevant Code

The PDF converter function

```
function pdf(sheetName, type){
    let ss_id = spreadsheet.getId()
    let sheet_id = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()
    let url
    //Check for type submitted
    switch(type){
      //Spreadsheet converted to PDF in portrait mode
      case 'portrait':
        url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss_id + "/export?format=pdf&gid=" + sheet_id
        break

      //Spreadsheet converted to PDF in landscape mode
      case 'landscape':
        url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss_id + "/export?format=pdf&portrait=false&gid=" + sheet_id
        break

      //If neither option works, then user did no enter 'portrait' or 'landscape' as their type option
      default:
        throw `${type} is not a valid PDF format`
    }
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
    }).getBlob()
    return response  
  }
```

The email validator function. I cannot use APIs currently, so this is my current workaround to validate if an email exists.

```
function validateEmail(email){
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.create('Email Validation Spreadsheet', 1, 1).getUrl())
    if(!new RegExp('[@]').test(email)){
      return false
    } else{
      try{
        ss.addViewer(email)
      } catch(e){
        setTrashed()
        return false
      }
      setTrashed()
      return true
    }
    function setTrashed(){
      DriveApp.getFilesByName('Email Validation Spreadsheet').next().setTrashed(true)
    }
  }
```

Checker to make sure something is an object

```
//Checker to make sure an object is an object
function isObject(obj){
  if(obj != null && obj.constructor.name === 'Object'){
    return true
  } else{
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: It is an expected behavior for a `switch` statement without `breaks` to process the first matching case up to the end because there is no escape statement (`break`). If you wish to trigger multiple cases that do not include the other non-matching cases, how about using multiple yet simple `if statements` instead? If you need further assistance, kindly edit your post so that it will be less confusing. In doing so, please highlight the minimum required code to replicate the issue you encountered as well as your desired output.

Comment: @Tanaike Apologies, I wanted to provide as much detail as possible. To summarize into a single question, is it possible to conditionally add an object to another object using the switch-case statement above? Because regardless of if it passes or fails the second case, the object is always created.

Comment: @PatrickdC Okay. Currently I'm just trying to push my understanding of JS further. The reason I don't want to add a break after the first case however is because there can be a situation where both cases pass. Is it bad practice to have use a switch-case in this kind of context? I also clarified my question some, and provided the remaining relevant function in the ```isObject()``` method.

Comment: @LoftonGentry, I get what you are trying to do with the JavaScript case statement and it is actually an interesting concept. However, I have tried it on my side without breaks and unfortunately it does not work the way we wanted it to be. Based from my understanding, the concept you are looking for is closer to a multiple (not nested) if statements code than a switch statement.

Comment: On the other hand, the case statement in your script is the only thing left to fix, right?

Comment: @PatrickdC that is correct, it was the only thing causing issues. If that's the case, then I'll just change it to an if statement check rather than a switch-case. This was more me trying to see if I could get something like the switch-case to work with conditionally creating and adding an object to another object. Is it possible to do what I am attempting to do, just not in this specific circumstance?

Comment: I think it is possible in some cases if you rearrange the order of the case statements and then strategically add break statements so that only the correct case statements will be triggered. But I find it somewhat difficult in other cases.

Comment: @PatrickdC okay that makes sense, but I see now how it’s better just to proceed with it statements over switch-case, among other reasons I further learned about from other posts/questions I’ve asked in the past week, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Replace the Switch Statements (with Issues) with If Statements

You can achieve the concept you wanted for your switch statements with if statements since the current switch statement that you use is not applicable in this case.

### Script:

Based on your post, you can replace the part of your script from:

```
if (arguments.length >= 4) {
  switch (true) {
    case validateEmail(arguments[3]):
      options.cc = arguments[3]
    case (isObject(arguments[3]) && arguments.length === 4) || isObject(arguments[4]):
      options.pdf = {
        sheet: arguments[3].sheet,
        name: arguments[3].name,
        type: arguments[3].type
      }
      tempName(options)
  }
}
```

To:

```
if (arguments.length >= 4) {
  if (validateEmail(arguments[3]))
    options.cc = arguments[3];
  if ((isObject(arguments[3]) && arguments.length === 4) || isObject(arguments[4])) {
    options.pdf = {
      sheet: arguments[3].sheet,
      name: arguments[3].name,
      type: arguments[3].type
    };
    tempName(options);
  }
}
```

### Additional Analysis:

Let me present some test cases with their corresponding output.

1. Switch Statement with Break Statements

---

```
function test1() {
  var data = 7;
  switch (true) {
    case (data < 5):
      console.log("Less than 5");
      break;
    case (data < 10):
      console.log("Less than 10");
      break;
    case (data > 5):
      console.log("Greater than 5");
      break;
    case (data > 10):
      console.log("Greater than 10");
      break;
  }
}
```

From this, the expected output should like the one below which is lacking:

[image]

This is the basic concept of switch statements wherein only the case which first matched with the switch expression is executed and then terminate the whole switch statement because of the break statement.

2. Switch Statement without Break Statements

---

```
function test2() {
  var data = 7;
  switch (true) {
    case (data < 5):
      console.log("Less than 5");
    case (data < 10):
      console.log("Less than 10");
    case (data > 5):
      console.log("Greater than 5");
    case (data > 10):
      console.log("Greater than 10");
  }
}
```

From this, the expected output should be the one below which included an incorrect output:

[image]

3. Proposed Solution: Multiple If Statements

---

```
function test3() {
  var data = 7;
  if (data < 5) {
    console.log("Less than 5");
  }
  if (data > 5) {
    console.log("More than 5");
  }
  if (data < 10) {
    console.log("Less than 10");
  }
  if (data > 10) {
    console.log("More than 10");
  }
}
```

From this, the expected output should look like the one below which should be just right:

[image]

### Reference:

[JavaScript Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: Please feel free to post further questions relating to the posted answer.